# MKPolyline only plotting points

Tags: ios, ios7

I am attempting to draw multiple MKPolylines for corresponding Arrays of lat/lng points.  However, when I addOverlay to my mapView the points are plotted but are not connected.

```
-(void)addAllRoutes:(NSData *)routedata{

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:routedata options:0 error:NULL];



for (NSDictionary *annnotationobject in json) {

    NSArray *polyarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[annnotationobject objectForKey:@"polyline"]];
    NSDictionary *polyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[polyarray objectAtIndex:0]];
    //NSLog(@"keys = %@",[polyDict allKeys]);
    //NSLog(@"values = %@",[polyDict allValues]);

    NSInteger pointsCount = polyarray.count;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[pointsCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++){
        NSString *lat = polyDict[@"lat"];
        NSString *lng = polyDict[@"lng"];
        CLLocationDegrees latitude = [lat doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longitude = [lng doubleValue];
        pointsToUse[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);


    }


    MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:pointsCount];

    [self.mapView addOverlay:myPolyline];


}

}
```

Route data comes via json text as:

```
    "polyline": [
        {
            "lat": 43.02038, 
            "lng": -87.897706
        }, 
        {
            "lat": 43.008363, 
            "lng": -87.892578
        }, 
        {
            "lat": 43.006454, 
            "lng": -87.891977
        }, 
        {
            "lat": 43.005188, 
            "lng": -87.891827
        }, 
        {
            "lat": 43.004029, 
            "lng": -87.891891
        }, 
        {
            "lat": 43.00302, 
            "lng": -87.89202
        }, 
        {
            "lat": 43.00184, 
            "lng": -87.892106
        }
    ],
```

Every point plots exactly as expected, it's just that no line is drawn to connect them.  Having a difficult time finding others with a similar situation.  All help/advice is welcome.  Can provide additional code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "polyline" element is an array of dictionaries (each dictionary has the coordinate for each point in the line).

`pointsCount` is set to the number of points in a "polyline" and then the `for-i` loop populates the `pointsToUse` C array.

The problem is that the coordinates are always taken from `polyDict` which ***never changes inside the loop.***

`polyDict` is set to the first coordinate in the polyline and is never updated in the `for-i` loop.
So you end up with a polyline with all the points having the same coordinate.

If you have multiple polylines, you will end up with "point plots".

To fix this, **remove this line**:

```
NSDictionary *polyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:
                             [polyarray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

and **add this line inside the `for-i` loop right before the `NSString *lat = ...` line**:

```
NSDictionary *polyDict = [polyarray objectAtIndex:i];
```

Now `polyDict` will point to the `i`th coordinate as the loop iterates.

Also, I assume you've already implemented `rendererForOverlay` and set the map view's `delegate` (otherwise nothing will show).

---

Unrelated but note that you don't need to `alloc`+`init` a new `NSDictionary` for `polyDict` -- just get a reference to the one that's already in the `polyarray`.

Same thing goes for `polyarray` -- just reference the one in `annotationobject`:

```
NSArray *polyarray = [annnotationobject objectForKey:@"polyline"];
```